# Windows batch file for services

Tags: windows, batch-file, monitoring

So, this file is supposed to check the status of 2 services and start them if they are found to be not running. It works well for the first service but how do I make it work for more than one services? Also, I want to be able to perform status check after it's started. Please let me know your thoughts.

```
net start | find "spooler" > nul 2>&1
if not .%errorlevel%.==.0. goto spoolersvc
goto nextSvc

:nextSvc
net start | find "BITS" > nul 2>&1
if not .%errorlevel%.==.0. goto BITSsvc
goto quit

:spoolersvc
net start "spooler"
echo spooler Service restarted at %TIME::=-% on %DATE:/=-% >> C:\scripts\isa\logs\spooler.log
echo

:BITSsvc
net start "BITS" 
echo Microsoft BITS Service restarted at %TIME::=-% on %DATE:/=-% >> C:\scripts\isa\logs\BITS.log
echo

:quit
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a batch file subroutine using `call`.  Once you call a subroutine you can jump to the end of the file and the batch fill will pickup right where it left off.  With this you can write a batch file that allows you to monitor and start any number of services.

```
set LOG_FILE=C:\scripts\isa\logs\spooler.log

call :CheckService spooler
call :CheckService BITS
goto :EOF

:CheckService
set SERVICE_NAME=%1

net start | find "%SERVICE_NAME%" > nul 2>&1
if not .%errorlevel%.==.0. goto :EOF

net start "%SERVICE_NAME%"
echo %SERVICE_NAME% Service restarted at %TIME::=-% on %DATE:/=-% >> %LOG_FILE%

net start | find "%SERVICE_NAME%" > nul 2>&1
if .%errorlevel%.==.0. (
    %SERVICE_NAME% Service started successfully at %TIME::=-% on %DATE:/=-% >> %LOG_FILE%
) else (
    %SERVICE_NAME% Service failed to start at %TIME::=-% on %DATE:/=-% >> %LOG_FILE%
)
```

Comment: Thanks @shf301. I tried executing the script but it's not starting the service up. Please can you check again and let me know what I might be missing? Thanks.